# Place name Vs name of geographical place

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Toponym is a synonym for place name.
A place name is the name of a geographical place.

A toponym is a name of a geographical place or a name derived from a name of a place.

I don’t seem to understand this. If you can see, the place name is the name of geographical place. The toponym is a name of geographical place or a name derived from a name of the place. Don’t they mean same? Place name and name of geographical place. Do they have the same meaning or different meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course *place name* and *name of geographical place* mean the same. These are just two different ways of explaining the word **toponym**.

*A name derived from the name of a place* refers to, for instance, a family surname which is also the name of a village.